# What is the point of hashing passwords in the database?

Tags: javascript, security, bcrypt

I noticed most api tutorials say that you should encrypt passwords before sending. It also shows how one can de-encrypt them. If I can do it, can't they do it too?

This is an example from [medium](https://medium.com/createdd-notes/starting-with-authentication-a-tutorial-with-node-js-and-mongodb-25d524ca0359)

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash){
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  })
});
```

They say to hash it here

```
bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result)
```

Here they unhash it when the user tries to login. What confuses me if the fat that if they can unhash it this easily, can't an attacker unhash it too? Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: No, you can't "unhash" the password. Instead, you hash the *attempted* password and verify that it hashes to the same hash as the *real* password.

Comment: @Pointy How will it hash the same if there is a random salt?

Comment: Because though the salt is random, it is exposed in the clear as part of the stored hashed value. Thus you hash the *attempted* password with the same salt as the *real* password

Comment: What you are saving to the database is not the users password, you are saving a `salt` (I believe). The user then holds the key, which is the actual password. So passwords can not be decrypted with a single key, because each key is the users password.

Comment: Oh. Ok. this makes sense. thanks

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn both the salt and the hash of the salt+password are stored. Modern systems like `bcrypt` also store some parameters to the hash function so that the computational difficulty can be increased for new accounts without losing access to old passwords.

Comment: @JermahlWhite you generate a random salt *once* for each user. You then save that and re-use the salt for logins of that user. So, let's say the password for `Alice` is `st0ng!23` and the salt is `p0weRful`, when when `Alice` logs in, you'll try to hash `passwordEntered + "p0weRful"` and only authenticate the user if the hash matches the hash you have stored. This way if user `Bob` also has the same password but his salt is `mUscls` the resulting hash would be different.

Comment: @vlaz why is the salt only being generated once? Does the encryption know that a salt for that has already been encrypted?

Comment: @JermahlWhite because you store the salt and add it to every hashing. If you generate a *new* salt, then the hash would be different. You can generate a new salt alongside each password change, though, that's fine. The idea is that `abc` gets hashed (using MD5) to `900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72` and if attacker has *that*, then they can just generate the hashes for all common passwords and when they find a collision, they have the password. If you add the salt `def` to `abc` before hashing, then the has becomes `e80b5017098950fc58aad83c8c14978e` and the password cannot be easily reversed.

Comment: @vlaz Should I let it generate my salt, or should I just make my salt something like `askafjsfasfasfas`?

Comment: @JermahlWhite Again I'm not familiar with `bcrypt` but I would *think* that there's some ready-to-use API that manages the salt for you. Generally the salt should be pretty darned long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that though I've written user account systems and used secure hash functions, I'm not any sort of "expert", but for those who've come to this question wondering whether you really have to go through the trouble of using a secure hash for password storage: **yes, you do.**

Furthermore, if you're still unsure, and you don't really feel comfortable in your understanding of how these hash methods work and how they support a security model, then you should be honest about that with whoever you're working for because doing security right is hard and requires experience and review by knowledgeable peers.

Anyway as mentioned in comments, a secure hash designed for password storage (like `bcrypt` or `scrypt`) has an API that handles all the messy work. I'm more familiar with `scrypt` but they're similar. The hashed password looks like a string of random characters, but at the start of the string are two separate parts that contain the random salt and the hash parameters.

Because a secure hash for password storage will always hash a password of any length and makeup into a hashed string of some fixed size, there's no good reason to limit user passwords to any length (other than something like 1000 characters just for avoiding DOS attacks).

Comment: Did you sell this to the community? How does it say owned by communty wiki?

Comment: @JermahlWhite The "community wiki" feature is for answers that, for one reason or another, shouldn't accrue "points" to the person who answered. Any answer can be marked (or changed to) being a community answer.

Comment: Why would you not want points? This  doesn't make sense to me? Well I guess when you have 300k+ rep 17 points doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JermahlWhite I think it ends up being a sort-of personal decision based on some dumb concept of "honor" or something :)

Comment: Ok. Seems legit :)

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the point of hashing passwords in the database?

It limits the potential consequences of a database breach since the attackers will not get plaintext passwords. This is very important since users often reuse passwords.

#### If I can do it, can't they do it too?

`bcrypt` is a one way cipher. Once the cleartext is encoded you're not getting it back.

When you check the users password you're checking that the result of encoding the user input matches the stored password hash.

This means that even if an attacker gets the salt and hash they still have to guess the password. Bcrypt has a built in cost (slowness) that makes testing a rainbow table of possible passwords extremely costly.